# Error while converting update/insert to Merge into

Tags: merge, teradata

I have an upadate insert SCD query which i am trying to convert into merge into as below:

```
    UPDATE A FROM X.CUSTOMER A,Y.T_CIF_CIS_CUSTOMER B
SET 
        EFFECTIVE_END_DATE =  CAST('2016-05-11' AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD'),
        DW_UPD_LOAD_TIMESTAMP = Current_timestamp(6)
WHERE 
        COALESCE(TRIM(B.UNIQUE_ID_IN_SOURCE_SYSTEM),'') = COALESCE(TRIM(A.UNIQUE_ID_IN_SOURCE_SYSTEM),'')
                                AND A.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE= '2016-05-11'
        AND B.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE<> '3499-12-31'
                                AND A.FILE_ID=B.FILE_ID
                                AND A.COUNTRY_CODE=B.COUNTRY_CODE
;


INSERT X.CUSTOMER 
(col1,col2)
SELECT 
col1, col2
FROM Y.T_CIF_CIS_CUSTOMER SRC1
WHERE 
     EFFECTIVE_START_DATE = '2016-05-11'
    AND EFFECTIVE_END_DATE= '3499-12-31'
```

I am using the below merge statement:

```
    merge INTO X.CUSTOMER TGT
using Y.T_CIF_CIS_CUSTOMER SRC on 
   COALESCE(TRIM(SRC.UNIQUE_ID_IN_SOURCE_SYSTEM),'') = COALESCE(TRIM(TGT.UNIQUE_ID_IN_SOURCE_SYSTEM),'')
                                AND TGT.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE= '2016-05-11'
        AND SRC.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE<> '3499-12-31'
                                AND TGT.FILE_ID=SRC.FILE_ID
                                AND SRC.COUNTRY_CODE=SRC.COUNTRY_CODE
                                when matched  then update  
                                SET    EFFECTIVE_END_DATE =  CAST('2016-05-11' AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD'),
        DW_UPD_LOAD_TIMESTAMP = Current_timestamp(6)

        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT values(
        SRC.CUSTOMER_ID,
SRC.CUSTOMER_LIFE_CYCLE_TYPE_ID...
)


/*WHERE 
                EFFECTIVE_START_DATE = '2016-05-11'
    AND EFFECTIVE_END_DATE= '3499-12-31'
;
  */
```

can anybody please tell me where i am getting wrong.Is it mandatory to use Only PI here as search condition?

Comment: What is the error message? The full PI and any partitioning columns must be included in the match condition of the MERGE.

Comment: Hi Rob,
Thanks for replying. I figured that out that it has to be a full PI.Currently we only have customer_id as PI. I am planning to put unique_id_in_source_system as PI and take customer id as a secondary index as this is used in various select queries for data retrieval.My question is how much impact does it have on the load as SI is created? Currently the Upd/Ins is taking lot of time.

Comment: Each SI on the table will introduce some overhead, but it should be tolerable if `customer_id` is the lone SI on the table. `MERGE` will be a block level operation and you should gain some efficiencies over `UPD/INS`.

Comment: Thanks, Rob for your expert advice :)

Comment: `MERGE` is logically used on matching PK/FK and there's no NULL in a Primary Key :) And as Rob already wote, in Teradata you must have at least all PI and partitioning columns (plus any additional cols). Can't you match on `customer_id` or is it different in source/target?

Comment: Hi Dnoeth,
No, we can't match on customer_id and the insert/upadate is taking lot of time. So, we are planning to make unique_id_in_source_system as PI and take customer id as a secondary index.

Comment: Hi @dnoeth,@rob paller,
I am again getting the error.."the search condition must fully specify the target table PI and partition columns....". Howevr, both my tables have have the same PI and that's the search condition anded together with some other condition. Any idea as to why i am getting this error?

Comment: You simply can't use COALESCE

Comment: Thanks, Dnoeth.Any workaround for that? I have few more doubts:
I have few more filters while inserting the record in my original upadate/insert( where condition at last). I am not finding a suitable place to fit those filters in my merge.
Also, one of the columns (surrogate key) is being generate like below while inserting:
SELECT (COALESCE(MAX(IPS.CUSTOMER_ID),0))  from X.CUSTOMER IPS)+  row_number() over(order by SRC.UNIQUE_ID_IN_SOURCE_SYSTEM).
This also can't be done while inserting. Any thoughts on how to achieve that?

Comment: I am able to add the additional filters. However, i still can't find any solution to generate the surrogate key logic in insert.